# What is the "fontconfig" folder in my home directory? May I delete it?

Tags: upgrade, fonts

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 12.10. In the process, a new folder appeared in my home directory called `fontconfig`. It includes some 24 files with a `.cache-3` extension. This happened on all my computers.

What is this folder? Can I safely delete it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In order to fix the bug involving [LibreOffice choosing incorrect font weight](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/1054204), a workaround of creating a fontconfig folder in Home folder during upgrading process was introduced. By right, once the upgrading is over, the folder should be cleaned up but hasn't been done.

I am not sure if there is any bug report filed for this. So, feel free to file one if necessary.

And you can safely delete the folder. The only purpose of the folder was to fix the bug during upgrading and was supposed to be cleaned up anyway.

Comment: Thank you ! I posted a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/1074778.